# user time locale settings - with javaScript (momentjs)?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So I am making some digital clocks with different timezones in each and I am done with the clocks, now I want them to show user time locale setting. So if it´s in America that it shows 09:00PM while in Europe it shows 21:00.

Here is a picture of the clocks

[image]

Here is the code:

```
var elementsDigital = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-timezone]");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementsDigital, function(elem) {
    var timezone = elem.getAttribute("data-timezone");
    elem.querySelector(".time").textContent = moment.tz(timezone).locale("en").format("LT");
});
```

Basically this code just get's some timezones based on what's in your `data-timezone` in HTML  and then using moment.js locales it transforms the timezone to english and displays the format wich is `LT` that is just hours and minutes.

So just so you understand me, I want to display the different timezones in my clock based on the user local time settings. So 01:00PM in america and in europe 13:00 and such.

Comment: Is there a question here?  I see no question.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer:

```
var elementsDigital = document.querySelectorAll("div[data-timezone]");
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elementsDigital, function(elem) {
    var timezone = elem.getAttribute("data-timezone");
    elem.querySelector(".time").textContent = moment.tz(timezone).locale(window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language).format("LT");
});`
```

Just: `window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language`